# Icomoon and text inside Placeholder

Tags: fonts, placeholder, webfonts, html-input

I want to use Icomoon and text inside Placeholder.

html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xe645; Search Contact...">
```

css:

```
input {
      font-family: "icomoon", "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: inherit;
  }
```

what i see:

[image]

this way I do see the Icon I want, but the text is missing (only the capital letters appear).
is there a way for me to add my own font for the text characters to my Iconmoon  generated files?